# One to Many relationship in Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

Im learning Ruby on Rails and I am practicing by making a small website. I am trying to make one to many relationship for a few models but I am having some trouble.

Currently I am stuck. I have a Users, ExpensePictures, IncomePictures models.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :expense_picture, :income_picture
end
```

ExpensePicture model

```
class ExpensePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

IncomePicture model

```
class IncomePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm stuck on how to actually make these relationships.

I want Users to have a `one to many` relationship with `IncomePicture` and `ExpensePicture`

I'm also not sure how to handle image files inside the model

ex:

```
User
    - user_id (primary key)
    - user_name

  ExpensePicture
    - picture_id (primary key)
    - user_id (foreign key)
    - ExpensePictureFile

  IncomePicture
    - picture_id (primary key)
    - user_id (foreign key)
    - IncomePictureFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as to handle images inside your models use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) (newer gem). Both very simple and easy to do the job.

Also take a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) railscast about Paperclip and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) one about carrierwave, very enlightening.

Besides, what's wrong with your relationship between the models ? Is it not working ? Cause it makes sense. Just use the plurals in your **has_many** declarations and I think this is it.

Comment: first time with this and im a bit worried if im implementing this correctly. Not sure how to test this as well

Comment: Since you're beginning in Rails, I seriously suggest you to follow some guide. Like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html for a tutorial and railscasts by mark bates. That way you will learn not only how to implement your models but also how you can test if it's working along with the view and the data is being sent to the db. As long as the modelling goes, you did fine I think. Natural mistakes, happens all the time. Don't worry about it. =)

Answer (score 5):

**Associations**

What you're looking at is something called [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - the backend relational database ([ORM - *object-relational mapping*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)) system

ActiveRecord is the "glue" which binds your Ruby classes (models) together, allowing you to pull data from a variety of different databases on your system. Any association inside Rails is governed by the ActiveRecord system - meaning if you can set it up correctly, you'll be able to get the associations you want

--

**One-to-Many**

The `one-to-many` association is one of the most common with Rails -

[image]

It works very simply:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :expense_pictures
   has_many :income_pictures
end

#app/models/expense_picture.rb
Class ExpensePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/income_picture.rb
Class IncomePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.income_pictures #-> collection of income pictures :)
```

This should be what you're looking for, with relevant documentation to help you

--

**STI**

A bonus for you: [Single Table Inheritance](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)

STI's are an *advanced* feature (so I wouldn't expect you to learn it immediately), but they will certainly help you with your current project. Basically, they allow you to define "parent" / "child" models which inherit from a *single* table (have a single `pictures` table, rather than multiple `income_pictures` and `expense_pictures` tables):

```
#app/models/picture.rb
Class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :expense_pictures
   has_many :income_pictures
end 

#app/models/expense_picture.rb
Class ExpensePicture < Picture
end

#app/models/income_picture.rb
Class IncomePicture < Picture
end
```

Why is this important? Simply, it allows you to just use a single table for both of these models (the `pictures` table will have a column `type` to identify the model which saved it)

This is a far [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)er way to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 1):

You must separate the declarations, and you must declare them plural versions (with a 's') like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_many :expense_pictures
  has_many :income_pictures
end
```

It's useful to go through the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

`one-to-many` association indicates that each instance of the model A can have zero or more instances of another model B and model B belongs to only one model A.

Example of how your models should be:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :stories
end

class Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Notice that has_many is always followed by a plural word: `has_many :stories`. It is also very important to correctly decide which model will have `has_many` and which will have `belongs_to`. The second model (Stories) contains one reference to the first model in form of a foreign key.

The second model doesn't know about the first model relation to it, it is not aware if the first model has reference to more than one of them or just to one.

You can read more about [rails associations](https://kolosek.com/rkolosek.com/rails-associations/) in this article.